# How to create a second border inside a div

Tags: css

I have a simple div with a border:

```
.box {border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; height: 200px}

<div class="box"></div>
```

I want to add a second vertical line that cuts the div in half, 30px inside the left edge of the box:

```
  30px     remaining width
____________________________
|      |                    |
|      |                    |
|      |                    |
|______|____________________|
```

Is there a way to do this with CSS3? I am thinking something to do with pseudo-elements but can't resolve the effect I want.

Thanks

Comment: Achieving this inside border with a pseudo-element is pretty straight forward (like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/emm1k0hu/)). But a bit more context on why it is needed might help in getting a better answer. Is it required as a background above which text can appear (or) should it separate content?

Comment: u can add 2 divs inside that and use the left div's border right..

Answer (score 3):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t9ar8njv/)  you can use [css pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```
.box {border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; height: 200px ;position:relative;}
.box:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:30px;
    height:100%;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

You ca use [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) too  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t9ar8njv/2/)

```
.box {
border: 1px solid black; 
width: 100%; 
height: 200px ;
position:relative; 
box-shadow:inset 30px 0 0 white, inset 31px 0 0 black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements):

```
.box {border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; height: 200px; position:relative;}
.box:after {content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:30px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nwvb22rg/

Answer (score 0):

```
.box:before{content:''; 
            display:block;
            position:absolute; 
            height: 200px; 
            border-left: 1px solid #000; 
            margin-left:30px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8m5gnga/